# Streaming an mpeg2-ts video over RTP using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, mpeg2-ts

I am trying to stream an mpeg2-ts video over RTP using gstreamer. I am using the following pipeline for the server:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/home/…/miracast_sample.mpeg ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000 sync=false
```

The problem that I am facing is that I get directly an EOS event like described below:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTPMP2TPay:rtpmp2tpay0: timestamp = 3878456990
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTPMP2TPay:rtpmp2tpay0: seqnum = 50764
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 126835285 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I can understand that it is running very fast but how to fix it?

Comment: did you get anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have set sync=FALSE, and that translates to "do not sync on timestamps, but process the buffer as fast as possible." Try and change it to TRUE, like so:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/home/…/miracast_sample.mpeg ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000 sync=1
```

Comment: same behavior with sync=1 and even without sync at all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and my coworker suggested I insert a `tsparse set-timestamps=true` between the filesrc and rtpmp2tpay.  It worked for me, so try changing your pipeline to

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/home/…/miracast_sample.mpeg ! \
  tsparse set-timestamps=true ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000 sync=false
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to demux it and then mux it ...

such as:

server:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=file_to_stream.ts ! tsdemux program-number=811 ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000 sync=1
```

client:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)MP2T-ES" ! gstrtpbin ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! mpeg2dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```